# Tokenize stringstream

Tags: c++

I need cut string stream according custom separator. Current code cuts just acording to several standart separators. How to define and cut `stringstream` to string line according to custom delimiter?

```
std::istringstream input;
input.str("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n");
int sum = 0;
for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line); ) 
    {
    cout<<line;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have one delimiter you want to use and it's a single character, you can just pass it to the 3-parameter overload of [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::istringstream input;
input.str("1;2;3;4;5;6;7;");
int sum = 0;
for (std::string field; std::getline(input, field, ';'); ) 
    {
    std::cout<<field;
    }
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/nOFye8)

For other situations (multi-character delimiter, multiple delimiters), you might want to consider using [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use third argument of overloaded `std::getline`

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line, delimiter ); ) 
{
   std::cout<< line <<'\n';
}
```